# How to convert an audio file into a CLOB?

Tags: java, oracle, clob

I am new to CLOB type of data objects. I'm using JAVA programming language to code.
My question is how to convert an audio file into a CLOB?

Should I convert the file into character array? or is there any other way?
Can anyone please guide me to a tutorial to do so?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to store a binary file in a `CLOB` rather than in a `BLOB`?  You could, of course, encode the file (for example, run it through a Base64 converter) and then store it in the database as a `CLOB`.  But it makes much more sense, uses much less space, and is much more efficient to store a binary file in a `BLOB`.

Comment: CLOB is for Character (Large OBject). You probably better use a BLOB (Binary Large OBject).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When refering toaudio files (*.wav, *.mp3...) you are probably dealing with binary files.

Oracle CLOB are for use with characters (Character large object), so you should rather use a BLOB (Binary large object). You should read your file (`FileInputStream`) and write every byte into the BLOB's output stream.